# What is the total number of classes available in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am preparing presentation, and would like to put approximate figure of total number of classes available in iOS SDK. kindly easy go, if the question is not a question.

If no link available, kindly let know how to figure it out ?

Comment: Why would the number of classes matter?

Comment: You can find out number of classes with [RuntimeBrowser](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser). But it includes private classes.

Comment: Contact apple, may be they knows exact number of classes available in iOS. :)

Comment: of course not the private classes  ;)

Comment: The private classes are the best ones!

Comment: Interesting, what sort of audience is interested in how many classes are there in a system?

Comment: Just a note. ;) every class on single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a brief overview of iOS and MAC OS X classes, use [RuntimeBrowser](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser)

And to check the APIs added with every release, [API differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS80APIDiffs/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 7.0.4 runtime reports 3138 classes on iPhone 4(6 of them do not conform to NSObject protocol) but you'd have to filter private classes somehow(and filtering classes which start with _ will remove only part of them). I'd say that around 500 of them are public, but that's a blind shot. And with each (at least major) iOS release classes count will increase.